# PDF of Own R Package

Tags: r, cran

I have successfully developed my own package and uploaded in CRAN. Now my problem is about pdf file of package.

From [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConvergenceClubs/ConvergenceClubs.pdf) it can be noticed that **two different Descriptions of package** (on page 1 and page 2) is appearing, but my *pdf* has one (only in start). Similarly, details  and references are also there.

### Q:

Now my question is how to add such two descriptions and there are some formulas (page 3) as details. How to add formulas format/ caption, etc. in own package *pdf*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ConvergenceClubs/ and dowload the source files. Unzip and you will see all the files the authors of the package you mentioned put together to create the package. By following this as example, you will be able to create your own package.

To answer your question, the first description comes from file DESCRIPTION that you see when you unzip, and the second one comes from a file in directory man (which stands for manual), file name ConvergenceClubs-package.Rd. All files that created the pdf are in the man directory.

The file computeH.Rd has examples of formulas.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You mean I have to write 2nd description before functions?

Comment: I got your point but can you help me to open .rd file. or paste that computeH.rd file material here.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. It is the required structure of the R packages. Have you been able to unzip that package? If so, you can open the .rd file with a text editor.